# Chrome Extension that replace a text in gmail chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I used Chrome Content Scripts to inject this script :

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(evt){
   var txt = $(this).val();
   $(this).val(txt.replace(/:\u06CC\s|:\u064A\s/g, ":D "));  
});
```

This must apply to chat textarea that appears after user wants to chat,
but chrome injects the script  between "document_end" and immediately after the window.onload event fires.

So it doesn't work.

Comment: Use "run_at": "document_end"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but as everything in Gmail is dynamic you probably should do a:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "textarea",function(evt){
   var txt = $(this).val();
   $(this).val(txt.replace(/:\u06CC\s|:\u064A\s/g, ":D "));  
});
```

Comment: Umm my fault document there should be without quotation marks as it is the global document variable. 'body' or any selector that is the ancestor of the textarea and it is present at the original source code should work, and maybe you should add aditional filters to the "textarea" selector to avoid messing other textareas that could appear on Gmail